MSBuild Error MSB4062: Could not loaded from the assembly when UsingTask with AssemblyName property
I got a simple task:
namespace MyLibs
{
    public class MyTask : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task");
            return true;
        }
    }
}

Then I tried to use them in .csproj. It's simple as well:
<Project>

    .....

    <UsingTask TaskName="$(AssemblyName).MyTask" AssemblyName="$(AssemblyName)"/>
    <Target Name="PostBuild2" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
        <MyTask/>
    </Target>
</Project>

When I built, I got this:

C:\Code\ConsoleTest\MyLibs\MyLibs.csproj(164,9): error MSB4062: The "MyLibs.MyTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly MyLibs. Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibs, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified. C
onfirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Then tried to use AssemblyFile instead:
namespace MyLibs
{
    public class MyTask1 : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task1");
            return true;
        }
    }
    public class MyTask2 : Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Task2");
            return true;
        }
    }
}

<Project>

    .....

    <UsingTask TaskName="$(AssemblyName).MyTask1" AssemblyFile="$(TargetPath)"/>
    <Target Name="PostBuild1" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
        <MyTask1/>
    </Target>

    <UsingTask TaskName="$(AssemblyName).MyTask2" AssemblyName="$(AssemblyName)"/>
    <Target Name="PostBuild2" AfterTargets="PostBuild1">
        <MyTask2/>
    </Target>
</Project>

Looking at the result of the build, AssemblyFile works, but AssemblyName still doesn't work. How does UsingTask work with AssemblyName?

Task1
C:\Code\ConsoleTest\MyLibs\MyLibs.csproj(169,9): error MSB4062: The
"MyLibs.MyTask2" task could not be loaded from the assembly MyLibs.
Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibs, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified. C
onfirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.


My MSBuild version is 17.8.3

It looks like you are trying to use the MyLibs assembly from within the project file for the MyLibs assembly. That's a type of circular dependency. The assembly is not available because it hasn't been built and it can't be built because the assembly is not available. You can't use a task assembly within its own project. You might consider eliminating the task assembly and using an inline task.

I've thought about that possibility, but there are two doubts : 1. why MyTask1 works? 2. MyTask2 was build after PostBuild1 target, the assembly seems to have been built at this point.

Try using the long form of the assembly's name, e.g. "MyLibs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

The assembly's full name is still not working as well.
